# How to submit a form in jQuery onChange() event - Bootstrap involved

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, submit, form-submit, onchange

**I have this markup:**

```
<form id="dpl" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="report_date">Svc Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="dispatchLog-container">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input id="dpl_date" name="start" type="text" class="form-control" required="" value="11/17/2015" tabindex="-1"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**and this jQuery:**

```
$('#dpl_date').on('change', function () {
    alert('pre submit');
    $('#dpl').submit();
    alert('post submit');
});
```

**Behavior:**

Both alerts fire `onChange()` but the form does not submit. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't preventing form to be submited? Maybe a 'native' bootstrap jq event. I'd try: `$('#dpl')[0].submit();`

Comment: Thanks @AWolf -- I'l give that a try now and postback

Comment: That did not work @AWolf

Comment: Just remove the space after on(

Comment: @H.Ferrence Error in console? Are you using duplicate IDs? Anyway, you have to provide MCVE.

Comment: But why would the alerts fire and not the .submit() if I remove some whitespace @GHOST93?

Comment: @H.Ferrence There is a space after your "on( "code at line please remove it and it will work.

--$('dp1_date').on( 'change')
++$('dp1_date').on('change')

Comment: @GHOST93 No, extra space as no incidence here and OP said event is fired as expected

Comment: @H.Ferrence I tried your code on jsbin and the alerts were started working after removing the space..

https://jsbin.com/lapebufiwe/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245248/submit-automatically-a-form-with-jquery-onchange-event

Comment: Cannot replicate issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/vLuahprt/

Comment: There is an error in the console on `$('#dpl')[0].submit();` which someone suggested as an answer. When I remove it and go back to `$('#dpl').submit();` there are no errors in the console and form still does not submit. P.S. what does "MCVE" mean?

Comment: @H.Ferrence And what error do you get when using `$('#dpl')[0].submit();`???  If you have something like `submit isn't a method`, then i guess you are using element with name `submit` somewhere in your form  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript

Comment: I get this error @AWolf `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function`

Comment: So, have you somewhere in HTML markup  (inside form obviously), element with attribute: `name="submit"` (check rendered HTML markup)??? See link in my previous posted comment

Comment: @H.Ferrence how are you checking that the form gets submitted or not? I mean how are you handling the POST data in your code??

Comment: yes I do have `name=submit` @AWolf -- maybe that's it. It is there because I have a submit button for submitting, but I am also trying to "refresh" the page on certain onChange() events. I gotta to into a meeting for a few hours so I am stepping away from this issue until later. Thought it would be an easy fix. Maybe we're onto something. I'll post back later.

Comment: @H.Ferrence Just set name attribute to something else, e.g `name="_submit"`. And for sure this is your issue. Next time, instead of letting us guessing, provide MCVE, not only part of code. And if you had tested your posted code, you'd have find it works as expected

Comment: Still does not work. Also, still unsure what "MCVE stands for.

Comment: Found it. It was both the `id="submit"` and the `name="submit"`on the submit button tag

Comment: Thanks for your help @AWolff. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you miss the action attribute in your form tag

I've you try :

```
$('#dpl_date').change(function() {
  alert('pre submit');
  $('#dpl').submit();   
  alert('post submit');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I just caught that after posting so I went into markup and added. But is still does not submit.

Comment: The `form` still should be submited

Comment: but if actions is not there it form will be submitted to the same page no??

Comment: @GHOST93 Ya it will. This answer cannot fix issue

Comment: `change(handler)` method is just a shorthand for `.on('change', handler)`